# Why i am Getting auto-Generated id in my live react website https://www.example.com/d/P908195

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, content-management-system, headless-cms

I have created a headless website using WordPress + React JS. The website is working fine, but we are facing a problem with the Google Search Console. In the Google Search Console, we have noticed that a large number of auto-generated links like https://www.example.com/d/P908195 are appearing. I don't have any idea how these links are being generated from WordPress or React JS. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Thank you!